# What is suitable ios version for the current Three20 sdk?

Tags: iphone, three20

I try to test one of my app in which I used Three20 sdk.
It worked on ios 4.2, 4.3.1 ipad
but exited immediately when started on ipod touch with ios 3.1.3

I just wonder what is suitable ios version for the current Three20 sdk?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developers at Three20 have set the iOS Deployment Target, which is actual the smalest version a project can run on, to iOS 3.0. So it should be o.k. to run your app on an iOS Version 3.0 or higher.

Three20 is not built to run on the iPad, so I think thats the reason why the app quits. In my own project, I always set the Deployment Target to iOS 4.0.